# Can I cast Stretch Weapon well before the battle?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

The casting time (1 swift action) suggests it is meant to be cast during encounters.
However, can I cast it in the morming, and use it in the first attack of the first encounter of the day?

Stretch Weapon (PHB2, p126):

> **Duration**: One attack
>
> *With a single utterance, the weapon in your hand elongates without becoming awkward or weighty.*
> The affected weapon stretches, extending toward its target, though it can be wielded normally. The spell adds an additional 5 feet of reach to a melee weapon for a single attack.

Comment: Duration: one attack. So your question is, can you cast it and hold it all day until you make that single attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, you can't

The reason is spell's duration. "One attack" is not the same as '[some dutation] untill discharged'. It means the whole spell actually lasts - is cast, takes effect, and ends - in confines of one attack.

This is all possible due to clause in a free action action type:

> You can perform one or more free actions while taking another action normally.

combined with:

> You can perform one swift action per turn without affecting your ability to perform other actions. In that regard, a swift action is like a free action.

It means that swift action may take place not only before or after but also **during** another action - an action part of wich abovementioned attack is. Note, it even lack somatic component, so cating it and attacking won't impede each other.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can come to an official ruling on this is to actually fast-forward to 3.5e, so take this with a grain of salt.

Let's compare the "one attack" duration to a "touch spell". In the case of a touch spell, the PHB explicitly states a touch spell can be held indefinitely so long as you don't discharge the spell.

I would treat this spell the same. It won't discharge until there is an attack.

---

From a more storytelling side of things, let's talk practicality. Your weapon has 5 additional feet of reach. The spell explicitly says your weapon stretches, so we can assume a physical change in shape. So let's say you have a magic sword that just extended 5 feet (you took your normal reach, added 5 feet to it, I believe it's safe to say the weapon itself grew 5 feet). Are you going to carry around a 7 to 8 foot sword all day?

*Edit*

That actually gets me thinking. You have a 7 foot sword. It accidentally drags on the ground. Does that discharge the spell? Does it have to be an intentional attack? Could you accidentally discharge your spell. Like when you rub socks on a carpet, get all staticked, then try to shock your friends. Chances are you discharge yourself unintentionally before you get remotely close to your prey.

I officially have more questions than answers.

Comment: PHB2 _is_ 3.5 as far as I know